# how to retrieve all product from the db using an id's list?

Tags: php, orm, cakephp

I have an array of products id's:

```
$product_ids = array(10,14,15,...);
```

and i want to find all the corresponding products on the DB using Cakephp's ORM. I'm using Mysql so the query would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE id
IN ( 10, 14, 15,... )
```

I could use the `query()` function, but it's seems like a sloppy way to solve this problem. Maybe i could use the `find()` function, but I don't know how... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Product.id' => $product_ids)));
```

?

Comment: wow... it works =D i just assumed that it wouldn't work. i guess that i underestimated the power of cake. Thxs!